# Otimização Algoritmo de Genética - Node.Js

Tags: node.js, algoritmo, otimização

Estou transcrevendo um algoritmo de genética de Java para JavaScript (Node.Js), mas estou tendo problema de memória e otimização.

Contexto do problema: é um algoritmo no qual a empresa onde eu trabalho está tentando implementar. O problema é que o algoritmo que possuo é em Java, e eles precisam que seja em PHP. Mas por motivos de adaptação e conhecimento estou tentando implementar em JavaScript.

Objetivo do algoritmo: Tender a chegar na combinação com menor preço de compra (aproximadamente. Lembre-se, é um algoritmo genético) para comprar um "baralho" de cartas em diversas lojas, levando em consideração o preço da carta e o preço de frete cobrado por uma loja.

Passos do algoritmo:

- Pegar dados das cartas (preço e estoque em cada loja)
- Pegar dados das lojas (preço de frete)
- Pegar informações do pedido/baralho (id da carta e quantidade a
  comprar)
- Gerar população (aqui está o problema)
- Fazer mutação na população
- Mostrar o melhor cromossomo gerado na mutação

Gerar população:
- Gerar X cromossomos, onde cada gene do cromossomo é a combinação Id_loja x Id_carta

Geração de Genes:

```
gerarGenes(vetCards, vetLojas, pedido) {

    let cont = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < pedido.getVetCodigo().length; i++) {
        this.vetTempCards[i] = Cromossomo.clonar(vetCards[pedido.getPosVetCodigo(i)]);
        let j = 0;

        do {
            const posicaoAleatoria = parseInt(Math.random() * vetLojas.length);

            if (
                this.vetTempCards[i].getPosVetQtd(posicaoAleatoria) > 0 &&
                this.vetTempCards[i].getPosVetPreco(posicaoAleatoria) > 0
            ) {
                this.matGene[0][cont] = posicaoAleatoria;
                this.matGene[1][cont] = pedido.getPosVetCodigo(i);
                this.vetTempCards[i].decVetQtd(posicaoAleatoria);
                cont++;
                j++;
            }
        } while (j < pedido.getPosVemNumComprar(i));
    }
}
```

Esclarecimento:

- "for" itera cada carta do arquivo
- Clona a carta
- "do-while" itera quantas unidades a carta[i] pede
- pega o ID de uma loja aleatoria
- verifica se esta loja tem a carta[i] com estoque e preço > 0, se sim, guarda o ID da Loja e o ID da carta no Gene. Logo em seguida decrementa o estoque da carta nesta loja

Erro do Node:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->
[21267:0x372d870]    16966 ms: Scavenge 1396.5 (1422.7) -> 1395.9 (1423.2) MB, 2.1 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.186, current mu = 0.117) allocation failure
[21267:0x372d870]    16972 ms: Scavenge 1396.7 (1423.2) -> 1396.1 (1423.7) MB, 3.6 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.186, current mu = 0.117) allocation failure
[21267:0x372d870]    16979 ms: Scavenge 1396.9 (1423.7) -> 1396.3 (1424.7) MB, 2.6 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.186, current mu = 0.117) allocation failure

<--- JS stacktrace --->
==== JS stack trace =========================================
0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x1cc9fff5be1d]
Security context: 0x1a3769f9e6e1 <JSObject>
1: clonar [0x287063151361 [/home/.../Genetica/classes/Cromossomo.js:~94 [pc=0x1cc9ffff5650](this=0x09d1fad477b1 <JSFunction Cromossomo (sfi = 0x64dcbcdd719)>,obj=0x0b60ffd23c99 <JSArray[87]>)
2: clonar [0x287063151361] [/home/.../Genetica/classes/Cromossomo.js:~94] [pc=0x1cc9ffff5812](this=0x09d1fad477b1 ...
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
<Mais mensagens .....>
Abortado (imagem do núcleo gravada)
```

Me desculpem se não consegui esclarecer meu problema... esta é minha primeira pergunta no stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver o problema de memória usando

```
delete this.vetTempCards;
```

Mas se tiverem opiniões de como otimizar este algoritmo seria muito bem vindas.

Estou tentando pensar em algo utilizando async/await